# Proof that adding an integer $k$ to the end of a prime $p$, $p$ times makes the new value divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

This was made as a remark in the last step of the proof to this problem below.  In short, suppose we have prime $p$ such that we can express $p$ by its digits as $p=a_n\cdots a_1a_0$ then writing the new number $p'=a_n\cdots a_1a_0kkk\cdots k$, where $k$ is an integer that is written $p$ times, we get that $p|p'$

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by the Pigeonhole Principle. Take the $p$ numbers (call them $b_n$, where $n$ stands for the number of digits) as mentioned and assume none is divisible by $p$, as otherwise we are done.

Now as we have $p-1$ possible remainders and $p$ numbers by the Pigeonhole Principle we must have at least to of them that leave the same remainder upon division by $p$, assume they are $b_m$ and $b_n$  (WLOG $m > n)$. Then we have:

$$p \mid b_m - b_n = b_{m-n}\cdot10^n$$

However as $\gcd(p,10)=1$ we have that $p\mid b_{m-n}$, which is a contradiction. Hence the proof.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused with $b_m-b_n=b_{m-n}\cdot 10^n$.

Comment: @johnfowles Maybe an example would help. Consider $m=5$ and $n=2$. Then we have $b_5 - b_2 = 11111 - 11 = 11100 = 111 \cdot 100 = b_3 \cdot 10^2$. Is it clear now?

Comment: I just tried example $a_2-a_1=777-77=700$ but $a_{2-1}=a_1 \Longrightarrow a_1\cdot10=770$.  Why does this example not work

Comment: @johnfowles It does work. Recall that $a_2 = 77$ and $a_1 = 7$. So that should do it.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: So just to be clear, the main theorem here is that if you have a prime $p$ and a list of numbers $(a_1), (a_1a_1),(a_1a_1a_1),\cdots (a_1\cdots a_1)$ $p$-times, then we know that one of the elements in the list is divisible by $p$?  What are the conditions?  I'm finding quite a few counterexamples.  for e.g if our prime is $5$ then writing $(6),(66),(666),(6666),(66666)$, doesn't give us any elements that are divisible by $5$.

Comment: @johnfowles It seems you forget that $\gcd(p,10) = 1$

Comment: Why do this only work for those $p$?

Comment: @johnfowles We have that $p \mid b_{m-n} \cdot 10^n$. To conclude that $p \mid b_{m-n}$ we must have that $\gcd(p,10) = 1$

Comment: Ok.  Thanks again for the help!